# logical OR and Bitwise OR

Tags: java

```
public class j68 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print(1==2||true);
    }
}


public class j68 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print(1==2|true);
    }
}
```

Both of above print true.Does it mean that we can use | instead of || ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, but mostly no, for a couple of reasons.

There's a big difference between `|` (bitwise) and `||` (logical): With a bitwise `|`, **both** operands are always evaluated. (I don't think there's any guarantee about which is evaluated first, either; at least, I'm not immediately seeing one in [JLS§15.22.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2), but perhaps there's a guarantee elsewhere.) With a logical `||`, the left-hand operand is evaluated first, and then the right-hand is evaluated **only** if the left-hand result was false.

This can matter if you're doing something defensive, such as:

```
boolean flag = obj == null || obj.flag;
```

That would fail if we used `|` instead of `||`, when `obj` was `null`; we'd get a `NullPointerException`.

Separately, there's the issue that others have to read and work with your code, and using `|` where `||` is normally used would be surprising. But that's a matter of style.